# SCSS images distorted

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, scss-lint

I have a round image that in a browser appears round. However, when I build the apk and run it on my android phone, the image is distorted (width greater than height). How do I enforce that it stays round?

I am using *Ionic 2*.

HTML:

```
<p class="item-selected-row search-right">
    <img class="item-stable" id="icon-image-{{subcategory.id}}" src="{{subcategory.icon}}" height="23" width="23" />
</p>
```

SCSS:

```
.item-selected-row {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.search-right {
    float: right;
}

img.item-stable {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `width` and `height` explicitly, e.g.:

```
img.item-stable {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I will try setting that in the css. I don't think it will make a difference seeing that it is sent in the html already though.